# What is wrong with this code? The answer should be 24 for this question right?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, infinite-loop, integer-promotion

What is wrong with this code? The answer should be 24 for this question right?

```
int t; 
vector<int>arr={24,434};

for(int i=arr.size()-1;i>=(arr.size()-2);i--)
{

        t=i;
}

cout<<arr[t];
```

Comment: ***What is wrong with this code*** Why do you feel something is wrong with this code? Do you face any issues?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like telling us the expected and actual behavior, and what efforts at *debugging* you have made.

Comment: Add `cout << i <<std::endl;` inside the for loop and you'll see what is wrong. `std::vector::size()` returns `std::vector::size_type` which is an unsigned intergral type while `i` is an `int`.

Comment: You have infinite loop, cast result of `arr.size()` to int.

Comment: And where did you get the shown code from? Did you write it yourself? Is it part of some assignment or exercise? An exam perhaps? Or an interview? I wonder because the loop doesn't make much sense, and might actually lead to undefined behavior if there was only a single element in the vector.

Comment: You could have seen a warning message "comparison of signed and unsigned integer values" thrown by the compiler if you enabled warnings during compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop

```
for(int i=arr.size()-1;i>=(arr.size()-2);i--)
```

is an infinite loop.

When i is equal to 0 it is decremented due to the third expression of the loop and becomes equal to -1.

And then in this condition

```
i>=(arr.size()-2)
```

as the operand `arr.size()-2` has unsigned integer type with the rank not less than the rank of an object of the type int  then due to the usual arithmetic conversions the expression i is converted to the unsigned integer type that corresponds to the type of the expression `arr.size()-2` and becomes a very big value due to promoting the bit sign.

That is in this expression

```
i>=(arr.size()-2)
```

the left operand can not be a negative value.

In fact this loop

```
for(int i=arr.size()-1;i>=(arr.size()-2);i--)
```

does not make a sense because in any case there can be no more than one iteration.

Comment: The loop is not infinite, it finishes with int overflow, so UB.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop never ends. Because an unsigned integer can never be -1.

Instead, try this smart approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main( )
{
    std::vector<int> arr { 24, 434 };
    std::size_t t { };

    for ( std::size_t idx { arr.size( ) }; idx--; )
    {
            t = idx;
    }

    std::cout << arr[ t ];
}
```

Output:

```
24
```

As you can see, the loop header does not have an update section, and the condition section also performs the task of decrementing.